# CSS Gradiant Page overlay?

Tags: css

I'm wondering if its possible to create a CSS Gradiant that overlays around the edge of the page.

I'm not sure if its a border as I want to to overlay the page, not add to the edge of it.

I'm running a Wordpress theme on a fulwidth setting, so being able to use CSS to implement would be great

So I guess my question is

1. Is it possible to create a CSS Gradiant Page overlay around each side of the page
2. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the gradient over your content, you can use `:after` on an element.  You can change the `z-index` also on your elements so that it appears above/below other ones.  You can change your opacity on this `:after` to make it more transparent as well.  Cheers!

```
.yourElementClass:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.3;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 0%, rgba(33,33,33,1) 87%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01)), color-stop(87%,rgba(33,33,33,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 0%,rgba(33,33,33,1) 87%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 0%,rgba(33,33,33,1) 87%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 0%,rgba(33,33,33,1) 87%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 0%,rgba(33,33,33,1) 87%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#03ffffff', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

Or if you're willing to change html, add a `div.cover` somewhere and apply this css to that element!  The jsfiddle reflects this approach.

Gradient Generator here:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5T953/1/)